# How to handle loading state for an image background?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, promise

I display an array of images. I want to display a grey background during the loading, the actual image once the promise has succeeded, or an error image if the process has failed. The images are retrieved from a server thanks to the url provided in the image object.

All images may load asynchronously. How to return a different background depending on the completion status?

My code is very simple:
`imageList.map((image, i) => <Image picture={image.url} />`

I am working with React.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes. It may be helpful

Comment: Thanks but this library only does lazy loading. I can't specify which background to display depending on the loading status.

Comment: Check this [Skeleton Loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loading-skeleton)

Comment: You can provide SkeletonTheme as well

Comment: @DoneDeal0 They have there https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes#css-api CSS API. Which can do that. I guess

Comment: @ParthPatel: I've just tried it, it works for lazy loading, but I can't display a specific image when there is an error or no-image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've found the following workaround with lazyload library, suggested by @ParthPatel:

```js
    <Image
      width={width}
      style={{background: "#eee"}}
      height={height}
      data-src={image}
      onError={(e) => {
        (e.target as HTMLImageElement).src =
          "errorimg.jpg";
      }}
      className="lazyload"
    />
```